# Recreate Expired Package In Sandbox?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, package, licenses

Okay, so I am pretty sure this request was just support being bone-headed. But they're not getting back to me, so I want to make sure.

**Is it possible to re-create a bug in a sandbox if it was caused by an expired package?**

As far as I can tell, there is no way to expire a package in a sandbox. However, my google-fu has failed to yield a definitive answer.

---

The backstory here being we had a bug yesterday where an inactive workflow that referenced an expired managed package blocked the insert of new `Case` records. Support has asked us if we can reproduce the issue in a sandbox to further investigate. However, as the issue causes data loss, we got the package extended as quickly as possible and do not want to expire it again.

Comment: If you were to burn a new sandbox, I'd expect the managed package to also show up as being expired. In that situation, presumably you could possibly duplicate the issue. It would depend on the real root cause of the issue as that could be a red herring. The fact that your workflow was inactive and still blocked the insert makes no sense to me, but I'm confident you'll sort that out with support. Try burning the box and let us know what you discover.

Comment: We got the package renewed. It was a pretty urgent situation so we resolved as quickly as possible. I should clarify in my post.

Comment: With that added piece of info, it would be pretty difficult to reproduce without the assistance of the ISV. It would seem they'd need to provide you with an invalid license to use in your sandbox.

Comment: Might be a misunderstanding here. Are we talking about the license on a managed package you created having expired or the license from a vendor of a managed package you use/pay for having expired? An ISV is an Independent Software Vendor of a Salesforce App on the App Exchange.

Comment: The latter. I've never developed a package myself. @crmprogdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, and support has closed my case instead of pursuing alternative reproduction steps. I'll work with my account rep to see if we can get something set up in a dev org.